# How to get a specific child divs value from parent using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question is so familiar in stackoverflow, but still I can't find my solution. I want to get my child div's value when I click the parent div, but my current code gives me "undefined". My html is given below:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="testId">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="testName">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="testDob">
    10/10/10
  </div>

</div>
```

and my script is given below

```
var id = $(this).child(".testId").innerHTML;
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Try `var id = $(this).children(".testId")[0].innerHTML;`

Comment: Why use innerHTML when you can use .html() or .text()?

Comment: One probable reason is if you click a child element of the parent then it will not work.... so try `$(this).closest('.main').children(".testId").html()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `find()`:

```
var id = $(this).find(".testId").text();
```

Answer (score 3):

"find" finds the elements just inside the div.main

```
var id = $(this).find(".testId").html();
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) no selector `.child()`

```
var id = $(this).children(".testId")[0].innerHTML;
```

or

```
var id = $(this).children(".testId").text();
```

or

```
var id = $(this).children(".testId").eq(0).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this one should works

```
$('.main').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).child(".testId").text();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a working exmaple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
               <div class="testId">
               1
               </div>
               <div class="testName">
               test
               </div>
               <div class="testDob">
               10/10/10
               </div>

            </div> 

    <script>
        $(".main").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).children(".testId").html();
            alert(id)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```